# Margin entre los div de bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Estoy haciendo una grilla con los estilos propios de bootstrap, sin embargo cuando utilizo `col-sm-*` los `div` están muy juntos y se pierde el efecto de `shadow` que les puse, les he puesto un `margin` a los div pero se desacomoda el último `div` y se baja, eso no es lo que tenía en mente, he visto que se puede disfrazar con la propiedad `border` igual al color de fondo del div padre pero esa propiedad la utilizo para otras cosas. He pensado en utilizar `outline` para ver si puedo disfrazar esa propiedad para que tome el color de fondo, pero aún no me queda claro como funciona. Dejo un snippet de cómo se ve sin `margin` y con `margin`.

**Ver el snippet en tamaño completo para ver bien los resultados**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 shadow p-5 bg-light border">
      COSILLAS
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4 shadow p-5 bg-light border">
      COSILLAS
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4 shadow p-5 bg-light border">
      COSILLAS
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 shadow p-5 bg-light border m-1">
      COSILLAS
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4 shadow p-5 bg-light border m-1">
      COSILLAS
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4 shadow p-5 bg-light border m-1">
      COSILLAS
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Si vas a trabajar el `container` con sólo 3 columnas y deseas que se mantengan en una misma fila sin importar la resolución puedes usar la clase `col` sin más. Bootstrap hace el resto del trabajo automático, dividiendo entre 12 la cantidad de columnas que agregues al contenedor.
[Fuente](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/#equal-width)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col shadow p-5 bg-light border m-1">
      COSILLAS
    </div>
    
    <div class="col shadow p-5 bg-light border m-1">
      COSILLAS
    </div>
    
    <div class="col shadow p-5 bg-light border m-1">
      COSILLAS
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```